# git - should source files and repository be on the same machine?

Tags: git, workflow

I plan to install a basic git server. The point is to, somehow, centralize projects development.

However, the computer where I would like to do this isn't that great. I have no more then a few gigabytes available.

Does this make sense?

- Each workstation will have their own git instalation and their own copy of project files.
- They connect to the repository server via ssh;
- The server will have only the repositoty information about the project.

Is this ok?

Edit:
 - It can be server-less if possible. The main point is, however, to allow everyone (3 persons uhh) to work on the same project. I'm a bit lost here... :)

Comment: you *could* go without central server but this isn't what you want. The central server approach is ok. Otherwise, you have colleague A pulling from colleague B and pushing to you and that stuff. Nobody can handle that. I'm using a central repo even for projects where I work alone (notebook, desktop have non-bare repos, central repo is bare, so I have three boxes with the full repo -> nothing will get lost)

Comment: eckes: the main issue here is, in fact, that of find a way to make all team members programmers AND designers, to work with git. That being said, big files should play a role. The accepted answer offered a solution, but it seems quite complicated to implement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you set a "central" git repository server, then that server will have [**bare** repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/738154/what-does-git-updating-currently-checked-out-branch-warning-mean/738256#738256) only (because of [push restriction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2147741/git-push-only-for-bare-repositories/2149539#2149539)), meaning:

- not *all* the files
- but only a compressed version of all the history of those files.

The space taken by those bare repos isn't that important if you are dealing with *sources* (text files).
But if you have, as a webapp designer, many binaries (mainly pictures), then you need to externalize them in another storage, while keeping your git repos in your central server.

The current solution is **[git-annex](http://git-annex.branchable.com/)**.

Comment: so complex for something that should help us out. :( If that's the only way... oh well... :)

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure what you are asking but.....

Git is a distributed version control system (dvcs), so where you have a repository you have all the files and all the history for the entire repository.

IMHO in a commercial development environment, it makes sense to have central repository from which official builds can be made, then your developers can push and pull into that repository or a "gatekeeper" can collate changes from your developers and push into the central repository.

Perhaps look at [gitosis](http://scie.nti.st/2007/11/14/hosting-git-repositories-the-easy-and-secure-way), [gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite), [github](http://github.com)

Comment: So... the server where the projects should reside, needs to have A LOT of space for hosting all those projects files, correct ? (I'm thinking also on the designer side of webapps where big files can be in place here...)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a program like [gitosis](http://scie.nti.st/2007/11/14/hosting-git-repositories-the-easy-and-secure-way) for that. And this is indeed a common setup.

Comment: One of the developers IS NOT over our LAN. According to your given source setup, could we allow such an access?