# Make a local copy of a remote git repository

Tags: git, version-control

I am not very familiar with the terminology or practices and procedures of version control.

Here is what I want to do :

1. I want to download a folder from a git repository from the Internet. Is cloning the right way to do it ? WOn't cloning keep the unnecessary meta-data files ? Is there a way to do a "clean" download ?
2. I want to set up a local repository that contains this folder on which I can now use version control. That is, when I do a commit, my local repository gets updated.
3. Finally, I want this local repo to be accessible on the local network, so that I can download it from any other machine on the LAN too.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

1. Cloning is the right way, but will download all the directories of your remote Git repo.
   See [`git clone` of Git Reference](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone).
2. The clone command will create a repo with a working tree already checked out in it, and a .git representing your full repo
3. You need to have at least a shared path in order for other to clone/pull/push your repo.
   See [git local protocol](http://progit.org/book/ch4-1.html).

If you are not familiar with those operations, I would recommend you to follow the simple exercices proposed by **[git immersion](http://gitimmersion.com/)**.

Answer (score 3):

You can't download single files or folders from a git repo, since git tracks the full state of a project as a whole, not just single files. There is a possibility to clone only a limited set of revisions (called shallow clone) from a remote repositoy, but such clones are restricted to a limited set of operations, for example you can't clone from a shallow clone, or push something from such a repo.

If the size of a git repo bothers you, you can `git gc` to make git reorganize the object database, which sometimes can get size improvements.

When you want to have a local cache, you can use `git clone --mirror $REMOTE_URL` to create a clone, which

- tracks all remote branches (see [What's the difference between git clone --mirror and git clone --bare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959924))
- is a bare repo (=has no working copy, see [gitready.com](http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/02/01/push-to-only-bare-repositories.html) or [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2147741/git-push-only-for-bare-repositories/2149539#2149539) why this is a good idea for a cache repo)
- act as a local cache, or a staging repo

You can clone new working repos from this local cache repo, and either push directly into the upstream repo (you need to `git remote add upstream $REMOTE_URL` in your working copy to add the link to the upstream repo, afterwards you can `git push upstream`), or you can push into the local cache repo, and push to the upstream repo from there.

Answer (score 3):

While `git clone` is the right for steps 1 & 2, you may need to have a read of a few of the git books e.g. Progit / Community book etc. to get a proper flavour of the best approach to step 3, and the git philosophy.

Git, as a *distributed* VCS, tries hard to avoid the "single central repository" that your "local repo to be accessible on the local network" might suggest. You can have a bare repo on the network, which allows *many* to push/pull from it, but this isn't the same as having your local repo on the network, with working directory, and *only you* using it as if it were a local drive.

Comment: Okay. I want to work on my project from two different machines and I want them to remain in sync. So I should put repository on one of the machines(say primary), clone it on the other machine(say secondary), add some "remote" link from the primary to the secondary and then do pushes and pulls to keep them in sync. Is that the way to go about it ?

Comment: If it is just you, and you work disjointly from the two machines (i.e. you're never using both concurrently aka logged in), then it is reasonable to have the repo on the network drive, and that way it is always in sync, no matter wher you log in from. Obviously you will incur some network delays, and you have to ensure backups, and its security, but it avoids phaffing with endless clones / pushes / pulls.

Answer (score 2):

Yes 'git clone' is the way to go. This will get you all the data and allow you to do commits. As long as the new repo is visible on the LAN, other computers should be able to clone from it as well.