# Why won't git push to a local repo update heads?

Tags: git

I've got a local repo `upstream` and a `downstream` cloned from it.  `upstream` has a non-master branch called `receiving` I use for pushing (neither repo is bare).

When I do `git push origin origin/receiving`, git properly pushes the commit objects over but doesn't update the HEADs in `upstream`.  I've actually fixed the issue before by opening the files in my editor and manually updating the hash.  I'd still like to to know if there's something I could do to make it automatic.  There aren't any permission issues - I'm actually doing everything as root with these repos.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2147741/git-push-only-for-bare-repositories - that branch you push to isn't the currently checked-out one is it?

Comment: No, I push to a branch "receiving" which is never checked out and exists only to receive pushes.

Comment: Why do you push `origin/receiving`? That's the remote tracking branch and it should point to the same commit in both repositories (unless `upstream`'s `receiving` branch was updated and you have not fetched/pulled recently)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your push command is wrong. You want to push the local branch `receiving` (or whatever you call it:

```
git push origin receiving:receiving
```

This should definitely work, here's an example:

```
$ git init upstream
$ cd upstream
$ touch foo && git add foo && git commit -m 'initial'
$ git branch receiving
$ cd ..
$ git clone upstream downstream
$ cd downstream
$ >foo echo "downstream change" && git commit -am 'downstream'
$ git push origin master:receiving
$ cd ../upstream
$ git show receiving --
commit …
Author: …
Date:   Sun Feb 26 13:40:02 2012 +0100

    downstream

diff --git a/foo b/foo
index e69de29..2ba104f 100644
--- a/foo
+++ b/foo
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+downstream change
$ git log --oneline --decorate --graph --all
* deadbeef (receiving) downstream
* c0ffee11 (HEAD, master) initial
$
```

Comment: Thank you!  I think it's also worth mentioning for anyone else who comes upon this to read up on refspecs in the manual page for git push.  Had I understood refspecs I wouldn't have asked this question in the first place!

Answer (score 0):

You have to do `git push origin receiving` rather than `git push origin origin/receiving`