# Deleted files still present in Git remote repo after push?

Tags: git

I'm new to Git, trying to get myself set up correctly. I have a remote repo and a local clone, with so far only the one (master) branch.

I deleted some files in local, committed this change, then did 'git push origin master', which appeared to work successfully. 'git status' now shows nothing to commit in local.

However, when I look in remote repo, the files are still there, and 'git status' shows them all as added but not committed. Should pushing my changes not have deleted them from remote? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why is your remote repo not *bare*?

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise I had to set it up this way. Can I change this now by running 'git init' again, or will I have to start again with setting up my remote repo? Thanks!

Comment: I've updated my answer to include instructions on how to make it bare.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you apparently push to a non-bare repository. A push will never update a remote working copy.

Have a look at [Git push only for bare repositories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2147741/git-push-only-for-bare-repositories) and http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/02/01/push-to-only-bare-repositories.html

To bring the non-bare remote repository up to date, connect to the machine where the repo is located via SSH and run `git reset --hard HEAD` and `git checkout -f` to forcefully bring the working copy up to date (note that this will destroy any local changes you might have done in that working copy).

To make your remote repository bare, connect to the machine via SSH so you can access it directly. Assuming the repository is in a subfolder `repo` run the following commands:

```
mv repo repo_old
git clone --bare repo_old repo
```

Then test if everything works and after this `rm -rf repo_old` to get rid of the old one.