# Deleted files in git repo still present in bitbucket account

Tags: git, bitbucket

I had a git repo in Bitbucket. I had cloned that repo inmy local machine using git clone command. All the files were synced in my local machine. I did some changes in that repo like deleted some files, renamed some file using

```
git rm -rm /directory
git rm /file name
git mv filename changedfilename
```

and push the changes using

```
git push -u origin master
```

After this all the newly added file and renamed files were displayed in the Bitbucket account but old one were also present which I had deleted locally. I had looked at the [previous similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10650382/deleted-files-still-present-in-git-remote-repo-after-push) but hadn't got any satisfactory answer.

Can anyone tell me what mistake I am doing?

Comment: Is your Bitbucket repo public? Were you viewing the `master` branch on your Bitbucket repo? Are you sure you pushed the right branch to the right repo?

Comment: Two tips: 1. Did you commit the deletions before pushing? 2. Use `git remote -v` to make sure that `origin` refers to your BitBucket repository