# Files kept in bitbucket after delete

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have the same issue as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22655201/deleted-files-in-git-repo-still-present-in-bitbucket-account) question, though there is no answer to it and it seems abandoned.

In short I have deleted some files from my local repository, and did `git add .`. `git status` says that the files are `deleted` and the `commit` also recognizes that I am commiting some changes, just when I `push` I get the message of `Everything up-to-date` and the files do not get deleted from my bitbucket account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do a `git add .` after deleting your files, your deletes are not recognised by git. You have to use

```
git add -A .
```

to force an implicit `git rm` of all deletes files.