# Git on windows over HTTP. post-receive hook not working

Tags: git, apache, githooks, git-post-receive, smart-http

I have configured msysgit on Windows as a server over HTTP. I have configured Apache server to forward the requests to `git-http-backened.exe`. When I cloned and tried to push to the server from remote PC, everything worked perfectly. But the `post-receive` hook is not working.

I have added to post-receive

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Hook got triggered.." > c:/Repos/logs.txt
```

When I manually execute the script, I see the log getting printed.

But when I push it from a remote system, files are getting updated. Push is working fine but the hook is not being invoked it seems, as the log is not printed.

Permissions for `post-receive` are `-rwxr-xr-x`

My `post-receive` used to send mails without any problem, when I configured git over SSH. After changing git to work over HTTP, I am facing issues. I have no clue, what extra changes need to be done to make the hook work.

Comment: Where is your post-receive hook? Is it in the `hooks` folder of the bare repo `xxx.git` to which you are pushing?

Comment: It is in xxx.git/.git/hooks folder. yea, xxx.git is the repo to where, I am pushing.

Answer (score 1):

> `xxx.git/.git/hooks` folder.

That wouldn't work: if the repo is a bare repo (as indicated by the naming convention `xxx.git/`, ie a folder ending with `.git`), then the `hooks/` folder should be immediately below it.

```
xxx.git/hooks
```

And when you setup a Git server, the best practice remains for that server to manage only bare repos.
See:

- "[Git push only for bare repositories?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2147741/6309)"
- "[What are the consequences of using `receive.denyCurrentBranch` in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25044077/6309)"

Comment: I did that, but there is no difference. Previously my repo was a normal repo, so I have put in xxx.git/.git/hook. Now i tested with a bare repo. For both it dint work.

Comment: @deepika but are you sure it is a bare repo? (http://stackoverflow.com/a/1830712/6309) And is your hook script named "`post-receive`" without any extension? (so not `post-receive.sh` or `post-receive.bat`)?

Comment: Yea, Now I am sure after knowing the differences between bare and normal repo. It is "post-receive" only with out any extension. The same file which worked for GIT over SSH. I read that there won't be any difference whether its HTTP or SSH for invoking hooks.

Comment: @deepika does it work when you are pushing (with ssh) to a bare repo `xxx.git/hooks/post-receive`?